# Web service design

Tags: java, servlets

I have a requirement from a user to have a web page where they can perform CRUD operations on a list of users stored in a DB.
It will be hosted on Tomcat.
I threw a quick Servlet together that takes 5 parameters from the request and creates a userName in the DB with this data. Now I want to allow the user the ability to enter a username and click a button and if this username exists in the db then it will be returned and the page populated to allow the user perform some edits on the data.
My question is,  should I just create a new Servlet for this data lookup service or somehow shoe horn the required functionality into the existing servlet that creates usernames in the DB

Comment: sounds like you better go with some REST framework like jersey: http://jersey.java.net/

Comment: To simplify that answer, your servlet can be split neatly to do three things - control actions (what to do in C,R,U and D), data (model) and view (show the output). People have found that it's useful to separate these three, so that wiring them to multiple servlets/programs is easy.

Comment: Karthik,  how would you typically control what action the request follows,  do you add a control/operation type parameter to the request?

Comment: MVC pattern is the best. Coz you have to know the basic JSP and servlet. In most websites they show creating these things in jsp itself and it is wrong. So follow MVC pattern. So all your requests should be from your jsp and the responses should be from servlets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's unreasonable to put this functionality in the same servlet. You're operating on the same resources (db) and the functionality is inter-related, so putting it in the same functional component makes sense.

I'd start to pull functionality into a different servlet when you're doing something fundamentally different e.g. operating on different databases, or there's some requirement to deploy that functionality separately (e.g. booking sales vs. browsing information), or you need to apply servlet filters differently for different components.

To answer your question below, you need to somehow distinguish between the different operations. Options include:

1. Modifying the URL path e.g. http://example.com/entity/update vs http://example.com/entity/delete. You can inspect the request path in your servlet
2. Provide an operation parameter e.g. http://example.com/entity?operation=delete&...

The first example could be trivially handled by providing different servlets mapped on different paths. However I think the overhead of providing those servlet and mappings outweighs the ease of simple checking the request path.

Comment: The reason I stopped to think about doing it that way is because I find myself looking in the Request for different parameters and following a different logic path depending on what parameters are there. For instance a "Create new user" type request will have 5 different parameters like name, address etc ini the request.  A "Look up username" request will have just a username parameter in the request.  So should I put an "operation" parameter in the request or how best do I differentiate between if the user is doing a lookup or is adding a new username?

Comment: Though modifying the URL path based on the request/action is a simple solution, I will not go for this because of

1. The application is not extensible. 

2. There is a security threat if the URL is visible to the user or we need to handle by putting all pages in WEB-INF directory and use only forwards

So it is  advisable to implement some design pattern like Front Controller or MVC pattern

There are a lot of sample programs avaialable and simple googling will help you find more.

one good one I came across is

http://www.java-only.com/LoadTutorial.javaonly?id=13

Comment: I think having one servlet implies a Front Controller pattern, doesn't it ?

Answer (score 1):

THE MVC PATTERN YOU SHOULD FOLLOW.

```
             JSP
              |
              |
            SERVLET
              |
              |
      ---------------------------------
      |       |         |              |
      |       |         |              |
SERVLET       |        DATABASE       JAVA LOGIC
             JSP
```

Answer (score 0):

A MVC design pattern suits more than anything in this case! Have a separate `Model` class for the look up operation. servlet in this case becomes a controller.